# Attempted to call an undefined method named "getQuery" of class "EntidadesBundle\Entity\Roles"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i got this:

```
public function getRolByIdAction(Request $request)
    {

        try{

            $inicio = $this->get("app.Ensession");  

            if($inicio->logeado($this) === true && $inicio->ver_rol("sistemas") && $request->getMethod() == "POST"){

                $filtro_busqueda = $request->get("filtro")["filtro"];

                $roles = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('EntidadesBundle:Roles')->find($filtro_busqueda);

                if($roles){

                    $response = new JsonResponse(
                        array(
                            'error' => false, 
                            'data' => ***$roles->getQuery()->getArrayResult()***
                        )
                    );

                }else{
                    new ErrorException(ErrorException::CONSULTA_SIN_RESULTADOS);
                }

            }else{
                return $inicio->logeado($this);
            }

            return $response;

        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            $response = new JsonResponse(
                array(
                    'error' => true, 
                    'mensaje' => "Error " . $e->getCode() . " -> " . $e->getMessage()
                    )
                );

            return $response;
        }
    }
```

the problem is that i dont know what i have to do to sent the **$roles** row that i found

i sent that

**POST Parameters**
Key     Value
filtro

[▼"filtro" => "1"]

can i return a json model from a find query doctrine?, is for symfony3, and i don't have the *@ORM/Id* in my *Entity/roles.php*

Answer (score 1):

You can not used getQuery() after a call to doctrine find method.
This method should return an ArrayCollection.

To serialize your collections of role you can use an bundle like https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle or used a native symfony serializer https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html.